# Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXMLElement [PHP]

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I load an XML file `$xml=simplexml_load_file("productsXML.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`
Then i want to delete the items that have a price lower than 16

```
foreach($xml as $item) {
    $item->suggested_price = $item->suggested_price  / 1.24;
    $timh = (int) $item->suggested_price;
    if ($timh < 16) {
      //deleting the specific $item
    }
}
```

After that, i recreate the XML with new DOMDocument

I ve tried lots of solutions in the internet without success. I can manipulate the under-16 prices or print them, but i can't somehow delete the whole $item.

XML SAMPLE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <products>
    <product id="25">
      <name><![CDATA[test]]></name>
      <name_en><![CDATA[test_en]]></name_en>
      <modified>2020-06-29T08:45:09+03:00</modified>
      <suggested_price>84.5</suggested_price>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short, representative sample of your xml.

Comment: @JackFleeting sorry i forgot it

Comment: The sample xml in your question is not well formed. Please edit again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('YourFile.xml');

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
$thedocument->removeChild(YourItem);
```

Can you show the code which u try?

You can Edit the Price right? then you propably need to Remove Parent!?

Comment: Yes i want to delete the parent. Please check the xml sample i added in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use unset, and for each time you unset continue the loop without incrementing the counter for the index.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("productsXML.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($xml as $item) {
    $item->suggested_price = $item->suggested_price / 1.24;
    if ((int) $item->suggested_price < 16) {
        unset($xml->product[$cnt]);
        continue;
    }
    $cnt++;
}
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Comment: Can't undestand why, but it doesn't delete all items under 16, seems to delete only the first

Comment: this is an infinite loop